# Extracting a div from parsed HTML

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

It seems that lxml/etree are generally imported as `from lxml import etree` -- why is that?  It keeps the code tidier, and while the potential namespace ambiguity might not be a concern, I don't have any incentive of doing this as it's generally frowned upon.

I know for a script of this size it doesn't matter much, but I'm going to be using these modules for a lot more. I'm also curious about what others have to say.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Stuart Powers http://sente.cc/

import sys
import urllib
import lxml.html
from cStringIO import StringIO

""" This script parses HTML and extracts the div with an id of 'search-results':
  ex:  <div id='search-results'>...</div>

$ python script.py "http://www.youtube.com/result?search_query=python+stackoverflow&page=1"
The output, if piped to a file would look like: http://c.sente.cc/E4xR/lxml_results.html

"""

parser = lxml.html.HTMLParser()

filecontents = urllib.urlopen(sys.argv[1]).read()

tree = lxml.etree.parse(StringIO(filecontents), parser)

node = tree.xpath("//div[@id='search-results']")[0]

print lxml.etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be confusing `from lxml import etree` that is a legitimate (even preferred) form of an absolute import with relative imports for intra-package imports that are discouraged: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ (see "Imports" section)

Answer (score 0):

In your and most of the cases I had while working with `lxml.etree` or `lxml.html`, there was only need for parsing and dumping, which in case of string input and output can be achieved with `fromstring()` and `tostring()` functions:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
```

Which would transform your code to:

```
import sys
import urllib

from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring


data = urllib.urlopen(sys.argv[1]).read()

tree = fromstring(data)
node = tree.xpath("//div[@id='search-results']")[0]

print(tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```